# firestore loading data in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

having problems to load firestore data into an array.

my code is:

```js
db.collection("vertrag").get().then((querySnapShot) => {
  array = querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data(), }));
  console.log(array);
});
```

which works fine

problem - at the moment i try to use my array outside the {} it returns undefined.

tried different assignments (let, const, returning via function), it doesnt improve - once outside {} i cannot use my array

please can someone help me - it can only be a small topic as the command itself works fine!

Comment: Try `const array = `

Comment: Where is array defined? i.e.
let array;
db.collection("vertrag").get()...

Comment: at the begin of the code with let

Comment: found out on other occasions that problems like this can also happen due to the time-lag of the set()-command. means - the program executes the code further below quicker and "takesover" the set()-command which results in being undefined as the array is still waiting to get filled...

Comment: tried with const also, same as let, no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
Where is array defined? i.e.
let array;
db.collection("vertrag").get().then((querySnapShot) => {
  array = querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data(), }));
  console.log(array);
});

// Now array will be available outside the {} closure.  However, the promise 
// is async.  So, you'll need to account for that.  If this is a react 
// project, for example, you would set the array on state, to trigger 
// any code that depends on the array.
```